# tty1 prompt before lightdm

Tags: boot, login, 13.10

After upgrading to 13.10, every time I boot I'm shown a login prompt (tty1) for ~30 seconds before lightdm automatically starts.

Everything works fine after that. Any ideas on what I could try to fix/debug this?

My `/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log` contains lines like the following:

```
** (at-spi2-registryd:1381): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
** (at-spi2-registryd:1381): WARNING **: Unable to register client with session manager
WARNING: Failed to open sessions directory: Error opening directory '/usr/share/lightdm/sessions': No such file or directory
** Message: PID 1534 (we are 1534) sent signal 15, shutting down...
** (gnome-settings-daemon:1401): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down
```

Searching for these errors results in a variety of bugs filed over the years. Maybe a clean install will fix this.

Comment: You sure you have `quiet splash` in your grub?

Comment: `/etc/default/grub` contains: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recent update seems to have fixed the problem.